# PHP show url and redirect to next in loop

Tags: php, jquery

I have array `[1, 2, 55, 76, ...]`

where I generate urls

```
www.example.com/id/1
www.example.com/id/2
www.example.com/id/55
...
```

**Question:** How to show each url for few second (3s) and redirect to next url?

My idea: use of iframe / jQuery

I am open to ideas/code/suggestions.

Comment: is javascript an option? Use a timer.  You could write a function and use .delay() to hold up the script before redirecting to the next location.

Comment: @TonyMancini `sleep` is used on the server side, he can't show the code before sleep then redirect

Comment: Yeah I realized afterwards... deleted the comment and asked about JS instead.

Comment: @TonyMancini JS/jQuery is possible too

Comment: how many element are there in the array and can you send them all to js then process them in browser side or it has to be requested each time for the next url?

Comment: @MaveRick cca ~6000 entries in array

Comment: That is a big amount of data and it's not right to send it all to be processed using `js`.
have you tried any `JS` code?

Comment: I'd create the array in php and pass the number you're on in the url, like www.example.com/id/55?loc=3844, then take that number and add 1 to target the next link in the JS `<?php $nextURL = $linkArray[$_GET['loc']+1]; ?>`  Then you can echo out that url in the javascript redirection script, this is assuming you're redirecting to pages that allow you to alter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JS solution. All URIs are written into an array by PHP, then a JS interval cycles through them:

```
var urls = ['www.example.com/id/1','www.example.com/id/2','www.example.com/id/55'];

var current = 0;
var interval = window.setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = urls[current];
    current += 1;
        if(!urls[current]) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

On the PHP side the first line will look like this (`$uris` is an array with all URIs):

```
echo "var urls = ['".implode("','", $uris)."']";
```

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xYzC6/).

Comment: perhaps `echo 'var urls = ', json_encode($urls);` would be preferable, as would using a closure variable referencing the iframe be, and actually setting the iframe's `src` attribute to the new url

Answer (score 1):

a pretty easy JS implementation would be this:

```
var interval = (function(iframe)
{
    var idx = 0,//current idx
        urls = <?= json_encode($urlArray); ?>;//array of urls
    iframe.src = urls[idx++];//set first url
    return setInterval(function()
    {//callback function, will be executed every 3 seconds
        iframe.src = urls[idx++];
        if (idx >= urls.length)
        {//we've just reached set last url
            idx = 0;//this resets the loop, after 3 seconds, the first url is used again
            //alternatively
            clearInterval(interval);//end of the loop
        }
    }, 3000);//3000 miliseconds, or every 3 seconds
}(document.getElementById('yourIframeID')));//pass reference to your iframe here
```

This line:

```
<?= json_encode($urlArray) ?>
```

Is, of course a PHP statement, and has to run server-side, if you can't alter the JS from PHP, you can get the urls through an ajax call

## [Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xYzC6/1/)

The fiddle loops through the urls twice, and then just terminates the interval, the `iframe.src` statements have been commented out, since the fiddle uses a div, but you get the basic idea